# Can I link to an HTML template above the parent directory in flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm currently working on Project1 for CS50W - the book club project. I'd like to link to it from my Project0 website. I got the project0 website all jinja'd out, and it's doing pretty good. Is it possible for me to put all the book club stuff in another folder inside the templates folder and still use my Template.html file for the jinja expanding? If not, I understand.

Template.html is in here:

```
 ..\01_WebProgrammingWithJSandPython\Quarantime\templates
```

Can I reference it from here?

```
 ..\01_WebProgrammingWithJSandPython\Quarantime\templates\BookClub
```

Here's from the app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_session import Session 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/bookclub")
def bookclub():
    return render_template("/BookClub/bookclub.html")
```

And here's from bookclub.html:

```
{% extends '../Template.html' %}
```